# AddScoped in dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have been reading and its best that I use AddScoped in my EF Core project so I can use many contexts for my updates , so I can stop the 'already tracked' error message when I am doing my SaveChanges.

Here is my code for the dependency injection. Just wondering how I can make this 'AddScoped' instead of Singleton ?

I am pretty new to this Dependency Injection, EF Core etc.

```
 public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // CCT database
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<sqldbCCTUKSATPPreProdContext>(
            options =>
            {
                const string ConnString = "SQLConnectionStringCCT";
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnString)).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
            });
        // CL database (Segimport DB)
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<sqldbCLSegImportUKSATPPreProdContext>(
            options =>
            {
                const string CLConnString = "SQLConnectionStringCL";
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(CLConnString)).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_)  registers context as scoped by default - see the default value for `contextLifetime` which is `ServiceLifetime.Scoped`. Your problem with "already tracked" comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I would have thought then when i do an SaveChanges then it should stop the already tracked problem ?

Comment: @Jason_Hough without minimal reproducible example I can't say much. My guess would be that you are fetching an entity with your query and then trying to add another one with the same Id.

Comment: @Jason_Hough: for us to answer that question, you need to post a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: @Jason_Hough and I would argue that it should be a whole new question =)

Comment: understood - i will write a new question about my tracking issue.